# how to update marker's location when is dragged

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have 2 markers one being user's location and the other  is a normal draggable marker and i get the distance between them, but no matter where I drag my marker I always get the same distance between them, how can I get an updated location when I drag the marker?  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To get the position of the drag marker, you should use an [`OnMarkerDragListener`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#marker_drag_events) to listen for drag events on a marker. To set this listener on the map, call `GoogleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener`.

You can get the position of the marker at any time by calling `Marker.getPosition()`.

Check this [issue](https://github.com/tristandunn/jquery-auto-geocoder/issues/8) and  [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829195/google-maps-error-markers-position-is-not-updated-after-drag) for more information.